# Converts 3 digit numbers to words C++

Tags: c++

```
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int num,
        leftDigit,
        rightDigit;
    string ones[] = { "Zero",
        "One",
        "Two",
        "Three",
        "Four",
        "Five",
        "Six",
        "Seven",
        "Eight",
        "Nine",
        "Ten",
        "Eleven",
        "Twelve",
        "Thirteen",
        "Fourteen",
        "Fifteen",
        "Sixteen",
        "Seventeen",
        "Eighteen",
        "Nineteen",
    };
    string tens[] = { "Twenty",
        "Thirty",
        "Forty",
        "Fifty",
        "Sixty",
        "Seventy",
        "Eighty",
        "Ninety",
    };
    cout << "Enter a Number " ;
    cin >> num; 

    if (num <=0 || num >=100 )
    {
        cout << "the Number is not Between 1-99" << endl;

    }

    else if (num >= 1 && num <= 19)
    {

        cout << "The Number you have entered is " << ones[num] << endl;

    }
    else if (num >= 20 && num <= 99)
    {

        leftDigit = num / 10;
        rightDigit = num % 10;

        cout << "the Number you have entered is " << tens[leftDigit - 2] << " " << ones[rightDigit] << endl;
    }

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

I've been playing about with the number to words and found an easy way to do any 2 digit numbers from 1-99.

Is there any way I could extend my current code to allow for 3 digits and allow for numbers 1-999 and how easy would it be?

Comment: Print the hundreds digit, the word "hundred", and then the two other digits as above.

Comment: Interesting that your code was actually copied from [here](http://besturdututorials.com/how-to-convert-numbers-into-words-in-c-urdu/). I guess you're just looking for people to do your homework?

Comment: Weirdly, despite being copy pasted, they somehow managed to misspell Seventeen in the original version of this post.

Comment: And theres already a Code Review on this question: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/60984/turning-numbers-into-text

Answer (score 0):

You can handle even larger numbers using recursion.
Use the fact that this program already works for 2-digit numbers, parse the hundreds digit with `num = num / 100` and pass the remainder `r = num % 100` to the function you created.
With a little work you can handle numbers in any length.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the algorithm in SQL (sorry). The `dbo.NumberWord` table has 2 columns: `Number` and `WordEn`. The table holds the English words for the numbers 1 to 20 and then 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80 and 90. (One, Two, ...Twenty, Thirty, Forty, ..., Ninety).

Here is the recursive T-SQL function that is called to convert any integer from 1 to 999,000 into English words:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fnNumberToEnglish] (@Number int)
    RETURNS nvarchar(1024)
AS
BEGIN   
    DECLARE
        @English nvarchar(1024) = 
            (SELECT CASE
                WHEN @Number = 0 THEN ''
                WHEN @Number BETWEEN 1 AND 19 THEN
                    (SELECT WordEn FROM dbo.NumberWord
                    WHERE Number = @Number)
                WHEN @Number BETWEEN 20 AND 99 THEN
                    (SELECT WordEn FROM dbo.NumberWord
                    WHERE (Number / 10) = @Number / 10) + N'-' + dbo.fnNumberToEnglish(@Number%10)
                WHEN @Number BETWEEN 100 AND 999 THEN
                    (dbo.fnNumberToEnglish(@Number / 100)) + N' Hundred ' + dbo.fnNumberToEnglish(@Number%100)
                WHEN @Number BETWEEN 1000 AND 999999 THEN
                    (dbo.fnNumberToEnglish(@Number / 1000)) + N' Thousand ' + dbo.fnNumberToEnglish(@Number%1000)
                ELSE
                    N' INVALID INPUT' 
            END);

    SET @English = RTRIM(@English);

    IF RIGHT(@English,1) = '-' BEGIN
        SET @English = RTRIM(LEFT(@English, LEN(@English) - 1));
    END

    RETURN @English;
END
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

string ones[] = { "",
"One",
"Two",
"Three",
"Four",
"Five",
"Six",
"Seven",
"Eight",
"Nine",
"Ten",
"Eleven",
"Twelve",
"Thirteen",
"Fourteen",
"Fifteen",
"Sixteen",
"Seventeen",
"Eighteen",
"Nineteen",
};
string tens[] = { "Twenty",
"Thirty",
"Forty",
"Fifty",
"Sixty",
"Seventy",
"Eighty",
"Ninety",
};
string hundred = "Hundred";
string thousand = "Thousand";
string million = "Million";
string intToWord(int num)
{
    if (num >= 1000000 && num < 1000000000)
    {
        int first = num / 1000000;
        return intToWord(first) + " " + million + " " + intToWord(num - first * 1000000);
    }
    else if (num >= 1000)
    {
        int first = num / 1000;
        return intToWord(first) + " " + thousand + " " + intToWord(num - first * 1000);
    }
    else if (num >= 100)
    {
        int first = num / 100;
        return ones[first] + " " + hundred + " " + intToWord(num - first * 100);
    }
    else if (num >= 20)
    {

        int leftDigit = num / 10;
        int rightDigit = num % 10;
        return tens[leftDigit - 2] + " " + ones[rightDigit];
    }
    else if (num >= 0)
    {
        return ones[num];
    }
    return "number too large or smaller than 1";
}
int main()
{
    int num;
    cout << "Enter a Number ";
    cin >> num;

    cout << endl << intToWord(num) << endl;

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

This code is tested and working.
You can expand it even further if you want to. It uses recursion which makes this really easy.

This code works till 999999999.

Comment: Please don't provide answers to the OP.  Provide information to the OP so the OP will have to think. :-)